# Double data output error using Freemarker and Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm working on a website using freemarker and spring mvc to render json data, But I found the double value such as "14.1234" will be rendered as '14,1234' when client's language has bean setted to 'French'.

I hava the value setted in the freemarker configuration files:

```
<xml>.....
<prop key="locale">zh_CN</prop>
<prop key="number_format">#.#####</prop>
</xml>
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In French you use `,` as the decimal separator. If you are printing not for humans, but for "computer audience", then you have to write `${myDouble?c}`.